# Identify if getselection() have cross different node

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I know that `window.getselection()` can help me to get the content where I selected.

Now I'm trying to write a function, to identify if user have selected the content across different node.

for example:

```
<li>
    first node
</li>
<li>
    second node
</li>
<li>
    third node
</li>
```

If the user select from the first to the third, how can I get where does the user's selection start and end, which node did the user start and end it's selection?

And if there are siblings and children between `anchorNode` and `focusNode`? Could I also get it's information?

Comment: [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `anchorNode` and `focusNode` properties of `Selection` object to identify the node which selection starts and finishes:

```
var startNode  = window.getSelection().anchorNode;
var finishNode = window.getSelection().focusNode;
```

Comment: How about if there are siblings and children between anchorNode and focusNode? Could I also get it's information?

Comment: The `Selection` object has a method named `getRangeAt` which returns one of the selected ranges in document. The returned object is of type `Range` and has many records which let you examine its contents. The `extractContents` method returns an instance of `DocumentFragment` object which let you query against its contents. For example its `children` property contains a list of all elements it contains.

Comment: this is not a complete answer to the OP, the second part is missing